# jQuery & ASP.NET validators conflict problem

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation

I have a page which has a form with a few validators. I also have a button (HTML submit) which resets form and clears all textboxes. The code works fine the first time I click the button, which clears the form. But if I refill the form and try to clear the form for the second time, it won't work. I also have other jQueries to toggle areas of code, they also stop working after this.
One thing to mention is that when I press clear form button, asp validators show themselves, which is odd to me because I have not put a validationGroup on them and not on my button. I think this happens because the button tries to do a postback.
So two questions, first what's causing my queries not to work?
And second, how do I stop the button from attempting to post back (which causes validators to be shown)?
The code looks something like this:

```
<script>
  scripts clearing the form and doing toggle actions here.
</script>
<form>
  label & texbox pairs to get info from user, accompanied by Required field validators.
  <asp:Button ... The Button to submit form />
  <input typ="submit" value="Clear Form" /> -->The button to clear form on client side.
</form>
```

Comment: In case there may be other causes to your problem, please post actual code.

Comment: actual code is pretty big, is there a place I can upload it and give the link? But I still put it.

Comment: you can try http://jsfiddle.net/ but I am not sure how big it can handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will stop the submit -- add a return false.

```
 $('#btnResetForm').click(function () {
            $('#<%=txtFname.ClientID %>' +
            ',#<%=txtLname.ClientID %>' +
            ',#<%=txtNatNo.ClientID %>' +
            ',#<%=txtBirthCertNo.ClientID %>' +
            ',#<%=txtUsername.ClientID %>' +
            ',#<%=txtCellNo.ClientID %>' +
            ',#<%=txtPhoneNo.ClientID %>'
            ).val("");
            return false;
        });
```

You might want to use `toggle()` and not show and hide to let buttons keep working.

Comment: they're not buttons that do toggle, they're actually radion buttons that make different areas diplayed and hidden.

Comment: I only speak english so I'm having trouble with what you are trying to do... sorry.

Comment: The controls that do hide/show actions are not buttons. They are radiobuttons as you may see in the code. Each radio buttons shows several areas of code and hides others. So it isn't exactly toggling, and I can't use toggle function. (It's not causing any problem any ways, but thanks for the advice).

Comment: You can enclose groups of controls in a div and then call `.toggle()` on that div -- maybe that makes it easier?

Comment: Not an option, what if a radio button is click two times?

Comment: You should not use the click event for radio buttons.  The event you should hook to is the change event -- then you are only executing code when the state changes from one state to another.  Click is not very useful for radio buttons.  (You would have to write code to know when state changes if you use click -- but it is already there, just use the change event.)

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of change event, but toggle still not an option in this particular situation. rad1-->display 1 and hide 2. rad2--> hide 1 and display 2. rad3--> display both. Can this be switched with toggle code?

Comment: Well the first two could (with two toggles).  However, the display both screws up the whole thing... you have to do it explicitly